# Why am I getting a 403 error when uploading to S3 from the browser?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cors, dropzone.js

So I've tried looking through previous answers on here and nothing seems to be working. I'm using Dropzone, which appears to make an OPTIONS request to get all the allowed CORS related information, but it doesn't seem to be returning properly

So from looking in the Chrome dev tools, I have the following Request Headers

```
Host: mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Origin: http://localhost:9010
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: accept, cache-control, content-type, x-requested-with
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost:9010/upload
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

And these are the Response Headers I'm getting

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
x-amz-request-id: 9BE37C4F32052EAB
x-amz-id-2: Zxg+v9AQ7G7sgMKz4P7xleUhrymyWGbBNNof8jFFsZ5n0Xw8T/mPovbMO55HZ5fL
Content-Type: application/xml
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Fri, 28 Aug 2015 18:35:26 GMT
Server: AmazonS3
```

According to the [AWS documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTOPTIONSobject.html) I should be getting **Access-Control-Allow-Methods** and **Access-Control-Allow-Headers** among things, but I don't seem to be.

I know my bucket is valid, and the url is valid and my CORS file in the bucket is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

So in terms of the form data that's being sent, I have the following:

```
acl
key
policy
x-amx-credential
x-amz-algorithm
x-amz-date
x-amz-signature
```

In addition to the file data. I don't think there's anything I'm missing

Comment: Something is clearly wrong, and it's not the returned headers. Amazon is returning a 403, which means it's actively forbidding you to visit that adress, so you don't have access. The question is, where's the data you're sending, and does it contain your AWS access key, the file you'd like to upload, the policy, signature and content-type etc ?

Comment: So I think I have everything, but according to [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-post-example.html) some of the fields like x-amz-credential are strangely capitalized (so it would be x-Amz-Credential). I tried that too and still it didn't work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Agh, it was super dumb. It seems according to the page on [enabling CORS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html) that for OPTIONS requests:

> Every header listed in the request's Access-Control-Request-Headers header on the preflight request must match an AllowedHeader element.

Meaning I had to add a bunch of previously missing lines to my CORS policy

```
<AllowedHeader>accept</AllowedHeader>
<AllowedHeader>cache-control</AllowedHeader>
...
```

Comment: I am uploading 8 files at a time on S3 through rails application. But after uploading all files, I am not getting callback in the dropzone succcess block. But if I upload 4 files then it is working. I spent 2 days but still not getting any solution. Please help

Answer (score 2):

According to the [docs on enabling cors](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html#how-do-i-enable-cors), you should be able to simply use `*` so you don't have to list them all:

```
<AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone struggles this, 403 can come because wrong contentType is set.

Server side:

```
GeneratePresignedUrlRequest rq = new GeneratePresignedUrlRequest(bucketName, objectKey);
rq.setContentType("video/*");
...
```

Client side:

```
$.ajax({
                url:upUrl,
                type: "PUT",
                data: file,
                contentType:'video/*',
                cache: false,
                processData:false,
                success: function (data) {

                }
              });
```

Comment: The wrong content type returns a 403 with `type: "cors"`?