# S3 Bucket using Axios giving a 403 in IE11 only

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, amazon-s3, axios, internet-explorer-11

I have a script where we are trying to submit a file to S3 Bucket with a presigned URL. This seems to be working fine in Chrome, Firefox, Edge, and Safari however in Internet Explorer 11.

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { urls } from './Urls';
import { getAccountInfo } from './GigyaService';
import { getAWSHeaders } from '../helpers/getAWSHeaders';

export async function receiptUpload(file) {
  const account = await getAccountInfo();
  const headers = getAWSHeaders(account);
  const presignUrl = await axios.post(urls.fileUpload.presignUpload, {file_name: file.name}, {headers}).then(res => res.data);
  const fileUpload = presignUrl && presignUrl.presignUrl && await axios.put(presignUrl.presignUrl, file, {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
  }).then(res => res.status === 200);
  const fileId = fileUpload && await axios.post(urls.fileUpload.receiptUpload, {file_name: file.name}, {headers}).then(res => res.data);
  const receiptSubmit = fileId && await axios.post(urls.fileUpload.receiptSubmit, {
    file_id: fileId.file_id
  }, {headers}).then(res => res.data);
  return receiptSubmit;
}
```

My first inclination is that headers aren't being sent correctly, however I would think that would also cause other browsers to fail. Also unfortunately IE11 does not really give you very detailed information as to what the resulting request headers are. So in Chrome the headers looks like this...

```
PUT /228ea8e2445144cfa89b8dbbc2d05e38/237-536x354.jpg?....
Host: test-images-upload.s3.amazonaws.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 35096
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Origin: http://localhost:4502
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36
DNT: 1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Referer: http://localhost:4502/content/loyalty/en/account/earn-points.html?wcmmode=disabled
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
```

and in IE it reports the headers as being...

```
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Access-Control-Request-Headers: accept, content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method: PUT
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 0
Host: test-images-upload.s3.amazonaws.com
Origin: http://10.xxx.xx.xx:xxxx
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
```

At this point I am completely stumped as to what the issue might be!

The above code appears to compile to the following from Babel/Weback

```
function _receiptUpload() {
  _receiptUpload = _babel_runtime_helpers_asyncToGenerator__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___default()(
  /*#__PURE__*/
  _babel_runtime_regenerator__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default.a.mark(function _callee(file) {
    var account, headers, presignUrl, fileUpload, fileId, receiptSubmit;
    return _babel_runtime_regenerator__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default.a.wrap(function _callee$(_context) {
      while (1) {
        switch (_context.prev = _context.next) {
          case 0:
            console.log('test');
            _context.next = 3;
            return Object(_GigyaService__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__["getAccountInfo"])();

          case 3:
            account = _context.sent;
            headers = Object(_helpers_getAWSHeaders__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5__["getAWSHeaders"])(account);
            _context.next = 7;
            return axios__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2___default.a.post(_Urls__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__["urls"].fileUpload.presignUpload, {
              file_name: file.name
            }, {
              headers: headers
            }).then(function (res) {
              return res.data;
            });

          case 7:
            presignUrl = _context.sent;
            _context.t0 = presignUrl && presignUrl.presignUrl;

            if (!_context.t0) {
              _context.next = 13;
              break;
            }

            _context.next = 12;
            return axios__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2___default.a.put(presignUrl.presignUrl, file, {
              headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
              }
            }).then(function (res) {
              return res.status === 200;
            });

          case 12:
            _context.t0 = _context.sent;

          case 13:
            fileUpload = _context.t0;
            _context.t1 = fileUpload;

            if (!_context.t1) {
              _context.next = 19;
              break;
            }

            _context.next = 18;
            return axios__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2___default.a.post(_Urls__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__["urls"].fileUpload.receiptUpload, {
              file_name: file.name
            }, {
              headers: headers
            }).then(function (res) {
              return res.data;
            });

          case 18:
            _context.t1 = _context.sent;

          case 19:
            fileId = _context.t1;
            _context.t2 = fileId;

            if (!_context.t2) {
              _context.next = 25;
              break;
            }

            _context.next = 24;
            return axios__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2___default.a.post(_Urls__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__["urls"].fileUpload.receiptSubmit, {
              file_id: fileId.file_id
            }, {
              headers: headers
            }).then(function (res) {
              return res.data;
            });

          case 24:
            _context.t2 = _context.sent;

          case 25:
            receiptSubmit = _context.t2;
            return _context.abrupt("return", receiptSubmit);

          case 27:
          case "end":
            return _context.stop();
        }
      }
    }, _callee);
  }));
  return _receiptUpload.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

Comment: https://www.charlesproxy.com/ can intercept the request and response from IE and tell you what the headers actually are.

Comment: Are there any other errors/warnings in either the console, or the network tab? Also can you see what the above code transpiles to when run in IE11? I wonder if there is something not quite right about what it is transformed to.

Comment: working on responses for both of you. thanks for chiming in :)

Comment: @scunliffe i supplied the transpiled code to my OP

Comment: Internet Explorer, the gift that just keeps on giving. Came across this [issue and solution][1], looks very similar. Possible duplicate? Could you change your request to fetch(PUT) / $.put to see if they too fail. Also what is stack returned?


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20489498/aws-signature-problems-with-ie

Comment: Is there any error in console in IE? The issue might be with IE CORS settings. Have you followed the steps about [enabling CORS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html)? You could also refer to [this article](https://www.webdavsystem.com/ajax/programming/cross_origin_requests) on what you can add to your headers when you are working with IE and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32277885/why-am-i-getting-a-403-error-when-uploading-to-s3-from-the-browser) for similar issue.